# How to autowire for multilevel inheritance class in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

In my project I have three classes which related by multilevel inheritance as bellow

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class A{


}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class B extends A{

}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class C extends B{

}
```

Now by using @Autowired annotation I want **C class** Object inside the **Manager class**

```
@Component(value = "manager")
@Scope("prototype")
class Manager {

@Autowired
A a;

@Autowired
B b;

@Autowired
C c;

......
}
```

Here **A** and **B** class Objects are injected by spring container but while injecting Object for **C** it is complaining as bellow

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.abc.bca.generator.sss.B] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: b,c
```

When I use @Qualifier for C class as

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier('c')
C c
```

or

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier('c')
B c
```

Still it is showing same error, so how can I get Object for **C** class.

Comment: I think the qualifier annotation should be on the class and not on the field. Try that.

Comment: I just tried your code(without @Qualifiers). I dont see any exceptions.. recheck your question

Comment: In my case it is giving same exception

Answer (score 5):

This wont work because, the extended class's(child class's) beans have parent's class name as the bean name since they are in the same type(parent's type) . So all three will have the same bean name `'a'`. 
Annotating with different names `'@Bean(name = "a")'` `'@Bean(name = "b")'` `'@Bean(name = "c")'` will resolve your issue.

For Example:

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B{
}



@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration{
   @Bean(name = "a")
   public void A getA(){
      A a = new A();
      //bla bla bla
      return a;
   }
   @Bean(name = "b")
   public void B getB(){
      B a = new B();
      //bla bla bla
      return b;
   }

   @Bean(name = "c")
   public void C getC(){
      C c = new C();
      //bla bla bla
      return c;
   }
}
```

Now you can autowire A,B,C from where ever you want.

Comment: how can I use `@Bean`, if possible please elaborate your answer

Comment: @Rajesh Hatwar,  I have edited the ans for the explanation.

Comment: Sorry I have tried the same way you suggested but no luck